# How to Always run Windows Store App as Administrator

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-store-app

**Is there a way to modify a Store App launcher to always run as administrator?**

Specifically, I'm trying to launch Ubuntu 18.04 (WSL) as an administrator by default. I can right-click and "run as Administrator" just fine but can't get this to happen by default.

For most .exe's it's possible to do "always run as administrator" via Security tab in Properties window of the .exe, for troubleshooting.

The only Ubuntu .exe I can find is `C:\Program Files\windowsapps\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_1804. 2018.427.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc\ubuntu1804.exe`.

But when I click the app launcher "Ubuntu 18.04" in the Start Menu, it doesn't respect the "always run as administrator" setting on the .exe. Further, when I "pin to start" the .exe, it creates the second icon in the screenshot. That makes me think that the issue is the Store App launcher that is in the start menu by default.

[image]

Comment: Running UWP applications as an Administrator cannot be done.  Ths is a limitation of the Universal Windows Platform.  Running a UWP application as an Administrator will NOT grant it elevated permissions like a Win32 desktop application.  As the Store Launcher itself is a UWP application, running it as an Administrator, will not result in it's own permissions being elevated.  The security context of UWP applications and Win32 desktop applications are entirely different.  What problem are you trying to solve by running the WSL instance as an Administrator.  That is a problem i can help with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suspect it isn't considered a supported use case, but I mainly want to be able to run amok with accessing/modifying files & directories as administrator.

Comment: My comment should not be considered an answer to your question.  UWP applications have specific restrictions on what files and directories it can access.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to make UWP apps launch with elevated permissions, it takes some configuration of the app manifest.

https://stefanwick.com/2018/10/01/app-elevation-samples-part-1/

Comment: I'm getting this error `Error APPX0501  Validation error. error C00CE169: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 41, Column 21, Reason: 'allowElevation' violates enumeration constraint of 'systemManagement lowLevelDevices'.` Something must have changed.

Answer (score 1):

From a .lnk file (a shortcut) it can be done from Properties>Shortcut>Advanced>Run as administrator.
[See in action.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6me3b.png)

You're requesting for a .exe (not shortcut) which can be done from Properties>Compatibility>Run this program as administrator.
[See in action.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpCGE.png)